# Choose between different steps depending on argument in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm using spring batch to write an application that read from a table and then write the output to a csv file. The application receives several input params, one of them is the database table to read. I want to write a single job that read the correct table depending on the input param. This is my Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class ExtractorConfiguration {

@Bean(name="readerA")
@StepScope
public JdbcCursorItemReader<ClassA> readerA(
        @Value("#{jobParameters['REF_DATE']}")String dataRef
){
    ...
    return reader;
}

@Bean(name="writerA")
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<ClassA> writerA(
        @Value("#{jobParameters['OUTPUT_FILE_PATH']}")String outputPath
) {
    ...
    return writer;
}

//endregion

@Bean(name="extractStep")
@StepScope
public Step extractStep(
        @Value("#{jobParameters['DATABASE_TABLE']}")String tableName
) throws Exception {
    switch (tableName) {
        case tableA:
            return steps.get("extractStep")
                    .<ClassA, ClassA>chunk(applicationProperties.getChunkSize())
                    .reader(readerA(""))
                    .writer(writerA(""))
                    .build();

        default:
            throw new Exception("Wrong table: " + tableName);
    }

}


@Bean(name = "myJob")
public Job myJob() throws Exception {
    return jobs.get("myJob")
            .flow(extractStep(""))
            .end()
            .build();
}

}
```

The idea was to add inside extractStep a second case in the switch (something like this):

```
case tableB:

            return steps.get("extractStep")
                    .<ClassB, ClassB>chunk(applicationProperties.getChunkSize())
                    .reader(readerB(""))
                    .writer(writerB(""))
                    .build();
```

and then write and exec methods for readerB and writerB; with this approach I'm receving this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope

I would like to know:
1- what is the error?
2- is there a method to get the JobParameters inside myJob rather than inside the steps?
3- is there a better approach?
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the scope `Step` is not defined in your config, adding `@EnabeBatchProcessing` should fix the issue as it adds it automatically. That said, how would you define which columns should be extracted from the table which is a dynamic? Are those passed in as parameters as well or you will do something like `select * ...`. With `select * ..` approach,  is the target type `DccDettTrim` generic enough to be mapped from all tables? If you have a reasonably few tables, I would keep it simple and create a job per table.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine; unfortunately I have already tried adding the @EnableBatchProcessing annotation but the error remains. In my idea , readerB() and writerB() use other target type ( es. ClassB).